# Why are the compiler generated Enums in Java final?

Tags: java, enums

I truly understand that it is not able to extend any class to implement an enum, since this would mean to have multiple inheritance. But what I don't understand is, why the enum classes, created by the compiler when using "enum" instead of "class" are final.

Is there any good reason why enums cannot be extended?

Plus: Is there any way to implement common behavior to different enums without Copy&Paste?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A *very* important aspect of enums is that the number or values are known at compile time (at least at compile time of the enum).

So if you have an enum like this:

```
public enum Foo {
  BAR,
  BAZ;
}
```

then you know that it has **exactly** two values: `BAR` and `BAZ`.

If you *could* extend an enum then you could introduce an `ExtendedFoo` enum that adds `QUUX`. Now since `ExtendedFoo` *would* be a `Foo`, `QUUX` would suddenly be a valid `Foo` value. And nothing would stop you from adding *any* number of additional `Foo` values.

This means that the compiler can no longer check if your `switch` covers all `Foo` cases. Similar static analysis steps are also no longer possible. Effectively your `enum` would cease to be a *special* type and there would be *very little difference* to a normal class with some pre-defined instances.

Side note: the generated `enum` class is [not *always* `final`](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#301974): If (at least) one of your enum values has a value-specific body, then the "base" class will *not* be final, but the compiler will *still* prevent you from extending it.

Comment: The part with the values makes sens to me, no doubts. Maybe I shall really use the interface way ...

Answer (score 2):

The common way is to create several enums and join them by implementing one common interface.

```
public enum One implements MyInterface {

}

public enum Two implements MyInterface {

}

public void process(MyInterface oneOrTwo) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: That's not exactly what I'm looking for, since any class could implement MyInterface and so I'd need to check if the class is an instance of Enum as well.
Plus: Using interfaces won't help me not using Copy&Paste for the implementations...

Answer (score 1):

Because `enums` are completely different, logically, from `classes`. You use `enums` to group things together, not for logic. Use classes for logic and enums... well... for enumerations.

What enum do you want to extend? Why would you do that? If there is a reason to do this, that means your structure is better suited to be a class.

Comment: Let's say I want to use enums to specify valid input parameter. In addition to use the enum in, for example, a switch statement, I would like to put some addition functionality what returns me a certain string for any parameter (the string used to set the parameter, adding a certain prefix, ...).